# Find out when QTMovieView has finished playing

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a QTMovieView, how will I be able to call a method when the movie has finished playing?

Answer (score 0):

I just ended up using:

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(method:) name:@"QTMovieDidEndNotification" object:nil ];
```